# Using Cassandra to count a big list of data

Tags: sorting, cassandra, counter, cql, nosql

We are using Cassandra to count various analytics metrics, broken down by account and date, which seems to be working well:

```
SELECT COUNT(page_impressions) FROM analytics WHERE account='abc' and MINUTE > '2015-01-01 00:00:00';
```

We would like to further break down this data by domain, which causes a problem.  The number of possible domains would run into the millions for some accounts over the span of a month or so, and we are most interested in the 'top' domains, meaning that we would like to sort by the `page_impressions` field.

Does anybody have pointers for me on how to count by domain and sort by total page impressions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra supports [counters](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html) which could be useful to create a top domain list in a separate table.

You might also be interested to use an analytics engine such as [presto](http://prestodb.io/) or [spark](http://spark.apache.org/) with cassandra, because its generally not very practical to adopt your data model for different analytics use-cases.

Comment: Hi!  I have tried both Presto and Spark - but they don't quite perform as I want - e.g. they bring back data in 15-20 seconds, which is amazing compared to Hive but not fast enough to power a UI.  If I invest time tuning, do you think I can get this down to sub 1-2 second querying?

Comment: You'll have to work with aggregations at some point across one or multiple dimensions. E.g. you could decide to create rollups for your metrics for hours and days. This can be done by either scheduling jobs that create aggregates on the end of the day or have this done "real-time" using solutions like spark streaming or samza. The idea with spark streaming would be to continously have you spark code applied to incoming data (ideally from a queue instead of c.) and write the aggregated results into cassandra. Either write exactly the aggregates you need or apply another spark job afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by Stefan I would definitely recommend Spark for analysis like this. Also be sure not to actually run a SORT if at all possible for Top N queries. These can usually be accomplished without the shuffle required for a sort by functions like

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

```
takeOrdered(num: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Array[T]
Returns the first k (smallest) elements from this RDD as defined by the specified implicit Ordering[T] and maintains the ordering. This does the opposite of top. For example:

sc.parallelize(Seq(10, 4, 2, 12, 3)).takeOrdered(1)
// returns Array(2)

sc.parallelize(Seq(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)).takeOrdered(2)
// returns Array(2, 3)
num
k, the number of elements to return
ord
the implicit ordering for T
returns
an array of top elements
```

and

```
top(num: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Array[T]
Returns the top k (largest) elements from this RDD as defined by the specified implicit Ordering[T].
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I have generally considered Spark a tool for ad hoc querying on Cassandra, but not for canned queries that need to be pulled back as instantly as possible (e.g. to drive an analytics UI).  Have you used Spark successfully in this capacity?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do and what sacrifices you are willing to make. If your data can fit in memory you will end up getting your RDD's cached in memory and sub second queries on large datasets are possible.